# How to write a function reference in a Perl module?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to figure out how to make a function reference work for a Perl module. I know how to do it outside of a module, but inside one? Consider code like this:

```
==mymodule.pm==
1 sub foo { my $self = shift; ... }
2 sub bar { my $self = shift; ... }
3 sub zip {
4   my $self = shift;
5   my $ref = \&foo;
6   $self->&$foo(); # what syntax is appropriate?
7 }
==eof===
```

Look at lines 5-6 above. What's the correct syntax for (1) defining the function reference in the first place, and (2) dereferencing it?

Answer (score 26):

TMTOWTDI

**Defining a function reference:**

```
$ref = \&subroutine;
$ref = sub { BLOCK };
$ref = "subroutineName"; # or $ref = $scalarSubroutineName
```

**Dereferencing:**

```
$ref->(@args);
&$ref;  
&{$ref}(@args);
```

Answer (score 11):

If `$ref` is a method (expects `$self` as first argument) and you want to call it on
your `$self`, the syntax is:

```
$self->$ref(@args)
```

Comment: The important thing to note in this calling style is that `$self` is not used to determine which method to call (as is usually the case when calling a method OO-style) -- the method is determined solely from `$ref`, and `$self` is merely passed as $ref's first argument. Contrast this to if `$ref` was simply the name of a method, in which case we would start looking for that method on `$self` and then up the inheritance tree.

Comment: @Jonathan: let's not turn SO[perl] into a group of salivating groupies.. the Jon Skeet fanboys are bad enough. :/

Comment: *I have a dream*, where answers are voted upon based on their content, and not by person that posted it.

Answer (score 8):

Use the following:

```
$self->$ref();
```

With this syntax, `$ref` can be a reference to a subroutine or even a string with the name of the method to call, *e.g.*,

```
my $ref = "foo";
$self->$ref();
```

Be aware that the two have slightly different semantics with respect to inheritance.

When you aren't passing explicit arguments, the parentheses are optional:

```
$self->$ref;  # also flies
```

Otherwise, use

```
$self->$ref($arg1, \%arg2, @others);
```